# Notice: Undefined index en formulario PHP

Tags: php, html

Me esta dando este error a la hora de pasar un dato desde el formulario. lo raro es que esta nombrado en el HTML.

```
<input type="text" name="celda_num" id="celda_num">
```

Codigo PHP

```
    $this->numero_celda = $_POST['celda_num'];
```

y me lanza este error

```
Notice: Undefined index: celda_num in C:\xampp\htdocs\PHP\CalcularValor.php on line 28
```

EDITO: AGREGARLE EL RESTO DEL CODIGO DEL FORMULARIO

```
   <form action="CalcularValor.php" method="post">
        <table class="tabla">
            <tr >
                <td>Mes: </td>
                <td>
                    <select name="selector" id="selector">
                        <option value="ENERO">ENERO</option>
                        <option value="FEBRERO">FEBRERO</option>
                        <option value="MARZO">MARZO</option>
                        <option value="ABRIL">ABRIL</option>
                        <option value="MAYO">MAYO</option>
                        <option value="JUNIO">JUNIO</option>
                        <option value="JULIO">JULIO</option>
                        <option value="AGOSTO">AGOSTO</option>
                        <option value="SEPTIEMBRE">SEPTIEMBRE</option>
                        <option value="OCTUBRE">OCTUBRE</option>
                        <option value="NOVIEMBRE">NOVIEMBRE</option>
                        <option value="DICIEMBRE">DICIEMBRE</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="separador-top">
                <td>
                    <label for="archivos_input">Numero de archivos</label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="number" name="archivos_input" id="archivos_input">
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label for="celda_num">NUMERO DE CELDA(Ej: A35)</label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="celda_num" id="celda_num">
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="separador-top">
                <td></td>
                <td><input type="submit" value="Calcular"> </td>
            </tr>

        </table>

    </form>
```

Los otros parámetros me los recibe perfectamente, menos el valor de ese input

Comment: Tienes ese input metido dentro de un <form> con un action apuntando al archivo php en cuestion?

Comment: Si, déjame edito el la pregunta para agregarlo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logré solucionarlo, reinicié mi equipo y funcionó de una, ¡que raro!